# how to manually install modules in qpython

Tags: python, django, qpython

I have downloaded django and other modules for qpython, then here comes the confusion, I have no idea how to manually install django for qpython, I thaught this should had been automatically. Please how can django be install manually. Thanks

Comment: check this to see this what you are looking for ?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the django or other dependency modules into the mobile's /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

BTW: you can install django through QPython's pip_console.py easily .